# CORS issue with Vue and Node

Tags: node.js, express, axios, cors

I am trying to create a website to practice Vue and I am building out a website for The Grateful Dead. I have curled my api and I do get a response in the terminal. However, I regret to inform I am running into a CORS issue and I haven't the slightest of clue on how to proceed passed this error.

In my Vue component I have this:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "About",
  data() {
    return {
      search: {
        year: null,
        state: "",
        city: "",
        song: "",
      },
      searchResults: [],
      error: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async searchInfo() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/setlist", {
          params: this.search,
        });

        this.searchResults = response.data;
        console.log("Updated searchResults:", this.searchResults);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching search results:", error);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**And in my server.js file:**

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
  })
);
app.get("/api/setlist", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://api.setlist.fm/rest/1.0/artist/6faa7ca7-0d99-4a5e-bfa6-1fd5037520c6/setlists",
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "x-api-key": "MY_API_KEY_TAKING_OUT_THE_ACTUAL_KEY",
        },
        params: req.query,
      }
    );
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching Setlist API:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error fetching data");
  }
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**The Error In Console**

```
Error fetching search results: 
AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_NETWORK"
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
: 
"Network Error"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=4b244e95:1451:14)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error
```

**When I clicked on the issue it states:**

```
Ensure CORS response header values are valid

setlist?year=1985&state=&city=&song=    blocked
```

Any help or direction would greatly be appreciated. I assume my error is how I am calling it from the front end, but I am not sure at this point, but that is my assumption.

Comment: "running into a CORS issue" - which issue? The exact error is needed. This isn't relevant to Vue as you'd have the same problem with Axios alone

Comment: I apologize, just updated!

Comment: Axios errors never serialise very well. What is the actual error reported in your browser console? It should be before the one logged by `console.error()`

Comment: ```About.vue:227 Error fetching search results: AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
searchInfo @ About.vue:227
await in searchInfo (async)
(anonymous) @ About.vue:140
(anonymous) @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1392
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:595
Show 4 more frames
Show less
```

Comment: ```About.vue:220
GET http://localhost:3000/api/setlist?year=1985&state=&city=&song= net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:258
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:146
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:172
wrap @ bind.js:5
searchInfo @ About.vue:220
(anonymous) @ About.vue:140
(anonymous) @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1392
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:595
Show 10 more frames
```

Comment: @Phil those are the only two things logging to the console

Comment: I doubt this is a CORS issue then. Looks more like your API server isn't running. Can you reach it with Postman or curl... `curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/setlist?year=1985`

Comment: @Phil that curl didn't work, but this curl does work to produce output in the console:

```curl -X GET 'http://localhost:3000/api/setlist?year=1985'```

Comment: @Phil last night I added this to my server.js ```app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
  })
);``` and nothing would work. I changed nothing and ran the server and site and now its working and outputting to the console. I have no idea why other than taking some time to link up because the amount of info regarding Setlist from the dead since it spans from 1965 to 1995